# Get the host pid from container id and its internal pid

Tags: docker

Given a container id and an internal pid, ie. "ps" output from inside the container, is there an easy way to retrieve the corresponding process id from the host?

Answer (score -1):

`ps` inside a container should give you a pid of `1` in most case. That's not informative.

To retrieve the pid of your running container from the host you should use `docker inspect` like that https://gist.github.com/petersellars/ffa2d63c20e881302493

Comment: docker inspect does give me process 1, but that's not what I am looking for. My container starts a process via systemd, and ps inside the container gives a pid that is different from outside the container (ie. host). The question is how to retrieve that pid from host's point of view, give a container id and process id inside the container (which is not 1 in this case)

Comment: I have troubles to understand your problem then. If you use `exec docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' "$@"` you will find the pid of the running process inside the container from the host POV. Isn't that what you want ?